# jar file problem

Tags: file, jar

when i tried to run jar file from netbeans it works fine but when i try to run by command prompt it gives me exexeption in thread error but when i check my task manager it shows the javaw.exe is running..............what it exactly and why this error comes only in command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

compile your application with:

```
>javac -jar example.jar ClassName.java
```

Run:

```
>java -jar example.jar ClassName
```

Comment: If your have more than one jar, pass all of them separated by semi-colon `;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste the exception that you get.

When running from command line, you have make sure that **classpath** for your program is set properly.

Make user that you have set the **main-class** in your manifest file of you jar.